# Value Query from PostgreSQL jsonb array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, jsonb

With

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tst.tst;
CREATE TABLE tst.tst (id int primary key, j jsonb);
INSERT INTO tst.tst (id, j) VALUES
(1, '[{"name":"aaa","val":3,"bol":true}, {"name":"bbb","val":1,"bol":true}]'),
(2, '[{"name":"ccc","val":5,"bol":false},{"name":"bbb","val":4,"bol":false}]');
```

I would like to do (in pseudo code) this:

```
SELECT * FROM tst.tst WHERE WITHIN OBJECT ('name' = 'bbb') AND ('val' > 2);
```

If I have an object instead of an array I can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM tst.tst WHERE ('name' = 'bbb') AND ('val' > 2);
```

As a json newbie I researched some answers here, tried a couple of things, eg this works, but is still far away from what I want to do:

```
WHERE '4' IN (SELECT value->>'val' FROM jsonb_array_elements(j)) ..
```

Maybe I'm close ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM tst.tst t, jsonb_array_elements(t.j) j
WHERE j.value->>'name' = 'bbb' AND (j.value->>'val')::numeric > 2;
```

The `jsonb_array_elements()` function is a set-returning-function so you should use it as a row source. In the above case it is [laterally joined](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) to your table so you can use columns from the `tst.tst` data. Every array element becomes a row with a single simple `jsonb` object which you can inspect with the standard operators. Note that the values, even for the `jsonb` type which stores numbers in `numeric` format, come out as `text` so you need a cast to `numeric`.

Comment: Thanks, sounds logical, I replaced json_array_elements by jsonb_array_elements, but it don't work. Should be the same for jsonb? `SELECT DISTINCT t.* FROM tst.tst t, jsonb_array_elements(t.j) j WHERE j->>'name' = 'bbb' AND (j->>'val')::integer > 2;`

Comment: sorry, empty result

Comment: My bad. The alias `j` is for the row source, the field is by default called `value`. See updated answer. The empty result is because there is no data that matches the filters. Try `< 2` and you'll get a row.

Comment: Great! `SELECT DISTINCT t.* FROM tst.tst t, jsonb_array_elements(t.j) j WHERE value->>'name' = 'bbb' AND (value->>'val')::integer > 2;` works as expected. Helped me a lot to understand the postgres json world, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If I may suggest, read up on the link I put in the answer, as well as the section immediately above it. That should help you understand how tables and functions interact.